# Deliver downloadable products from a sub-domain?

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, downloadable

How can Magento be configured to deliver downloadable products from a sub-domain.

Currently:

https://example.com/downloadable/download/link/id/SECRET_KEY/

Desired:

https://download.example.com/downloadable/download/link/id/SECRET_KEY/

Note: the store is configured so that downloadable links cannot be shared, i.e. the customer must be logged in his own account to download the product.

Answer (score 3):

### Basics

Start of by adding a second storeview with new urls.
This example focuses on 1 store.

- goto `System / Stores`
- create a storeview **Downloads** (set *download* as code)
- goto `System / Configuration / General->Web`
- set the correct `base urls` for `secure` and `unsecure`

You can play with the `Session cookie management` to make crossdomain cookies so the users do not have to login if it is under the same domain.

### Replace downloadable links

Now you have to lookup the places where the downloadlink is generated:
There are two locations I found important:

- `app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Block/Customer/Products/List.php` for the customer list page
- `app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Block/Sales/Order/Email/Items/Order/Downloadable.php` in the e-mails

Create a custom module and rewrite the download functions:

**Downloads on account page**

```
class Custom_Downloadable_Block_Downloadable_Customer_Products_List
        extends Mage_Downloadable_Block_Customer_Products_List
{

    /**
     * Return url to download link
     *
     * @param Mage_Downloadable_Model_Link_Purchased_Item $item
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDownloadUrl($item)
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/download/link', array(
                'id' => $item->getLinkHash(),
                '_secure' => true,
                '_store' => 'download' /* Use download store */
        ));
    }

}
```

**Downloads in e-mail links**

```
class Custom_Downloadable_Block_Downloadable_Sales_Order_Email_Items_Order_Downloadable
        extends Mage_Downloadable_Block_Sales_Order_Email_Items_Order_Downloadable {


    public function getPurchasedLinkUrl($item)
    {
        return $this->getUrl('downloadable/download/link', array(
                'id'        => $item->getLinkHash(),
                '_store'    => 'download', /* Always download from download store */
                '_secure'   => true,
                '_nosid'    => true
        ));
    }

}
```